# Raspberry PI AD8232

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to program an AD8232 heart monitor using a Raspberry PI, As far as I can make out I have all the right packages installed for ump and ADC ads1115. The problem I am having is when I try to run the code I get a Value Error:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/upm/pyupm_ad8232.py", line 170, in init
this = _pyupm_ad8232.new_AD8232(loPlus, loMinus, output, aref)
ValueError: UPM Invalid Argument: Invalid AIO pin specified - do you have an ADC?
Can anybody help with this problem, the python script I am using is below
Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from __future__ import print_function
import time, sys, signal, atexit
from upm import pyupm_ad8232 as upmAD8232
from upm import pyupm_ads1x15 as upm

def main():
    # Instantiate a AD8232 sensor on digital pins 10 (LO+), 11 (LO-)
    # and an analog pin, 0 (OUTPUT)
    myAD8232 = upmAD8232.AD8232(10, 11, 8)

    ## Exit handlers ##
    # This function stops python from printing a stacktrace when you hit 

def SIGINTHandler(signum, frame):
        raise SystemExit

    # This function lets you run code on exit, including functions from        myAD8232
def exitHandler():
    print("Exiting")
    sys.exit(0)

    # Register exit handlers
    atexit.register(exitHandler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, SIGINTHandler)

    # Output the raw numbers from the ADC, for plotting elsewhere.
    # A return of 0 indicates a Lead Off (LO) condition.
    # In theory, this data could be fed to software like Processing
    # (https://www.processing.org/) to plot the data just like an
    # EKG you would see in a hospital.
    while(1):
        print(myAD8232.value())
        time.sleep(.001)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ADS 1110 or 1115 n make connections with raspberry, out pin of heart rate sensor to A0 pin of ADS 1110

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Raspberry Pi does not have an Analog Input pin, so you cannot connect it directly to an AD8232.
You've told the program you have an Analog input on GPIO8 (code says: myAD8232 = upmAD8232.AD8232(10, 11, 8), but you don't!
[In passing, the associated comment refers to it being on pin GPIO0, but the code itself says GPIO8]

Your question says you have added an ADC, and your code installs the driver for it, but you have not added any code to read the now digital value and use that instead of the expected Analog pin.